# Steps for billing at Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am planning to list a Gmail Contextual Gadget on Google Apps Marketplace. More than a year ago I created a vendor profile and a listing (so I am familiar with those steps), but I never made the gadget commercial. Now I'm ready for setting up the gadget for sale but I am wondering about the billing is implemented. As I've read in the Marketplace billing [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/#bill), Google does not provide any solution for this, but recommends that I implement it myself or use a third-party billing product.

So my questions are:
- Which are the basic steps to create a billing solution for your listing?
- Is there any way keep the payment "manual", in that sense that I enable the product for installation manually (with a token etc) for a customer when the payment is received?
- How long time do I have to estimate for this?

Really appreciate an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Licensing api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/licensing